# Unable to update the review

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

"""model.py"""

```
    class Review(db.Model):

        __tablename__ = "reviews"
    
        review_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
        user_review = db.Column(db.Text)
        movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("movies.movie_id"))
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.user_id"))
    
        user =  db.relationship("User", back_populates="reviews")
        movie = db.relationship("Movie", back_populates="reviews")
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"<Review review_id={self.review_id} score={self.user_review}>"
```

"""CRUD.py"""`

```
    def update_review(review_id, new_review):
    review = Review.query.get(review_id)
    review.review = new_review
    db.session.commit()\`
```

"""main.py"""

```
    @app.route("/update_review", methods=\["POST"\])
    def update_review():
    review_id = request.json\["review_id"\]
    updated_review = request.json\["updated_review"\]
    crud.update.review(review_id, updated_review)
    db.session.commit()

        flash(f"You have updated this movie!")  #THIS DOESN"T WORK!!!
    
        return "Success"
```

"""updateReview.js"""

```
const editReviewButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-movie-review');

    for (const button of editButtons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () =\> {
    
        const newReview = prompt('Please update your review');
        const reviewID = button.id;
        const formInputs = {
          "review_id": reviewID,
          "updated_review": newReview,
        };
    
    
        fetch('/update_review', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(formInputs),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
            const reviewHTML = document.querySelector(`#review_${reviewID}`);
            reviewHTML.innerHTML = newReview; //using the DOM manipulation to change what's on the page
        })
    
    })
    }
```

"""movie_details.html"""

```
    <kbd>\<ul\>
    {% for review in user.reviews %}
    \<li\>
    {{review.movie.title}}: \<span id="review\_{{ review.review_id }}"\>{{ review.user_review         }}\</span\>
    {% if session.get("user_email") == user.email %}
    <button class="edit-movie-review" id="{{ review.review_id }}"\> Edit review \</button\>  
    {% endif %}
    </li\>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul\>
    </br\></kbd>
```

1. I created the review.
2. It is saved in the database.
3. I went to the .html and entered the new review.
4. but it didn't update the review.
5. major problem: the new review cannot be updated in the database.

I don't understand why the review doesn't get updated.